# use a custom post type as a category of another post type wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a websites about soccer and I want to display a games information ex: Real madrid vs FCB so the Game have teams I want when I am creating a game to select teams and the team will be clickable so it redirects you the the team-single.php. game have 2 teams and team belongs to a game.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way to accomplish this would be via Advanced Custom Fields plugin. It allows you to assign all sorts of really useful data / selections to content on the backend of your site.

I'd probably approach this as follows:

1. Once ACF is installed, create a field group with a field of "Teams",
   with a field type of "Post Object"
2. In the Post Type select, choose your "teams" custom post type.
3. Choose "Yes" for Select Multiple Values?
4. Finally, in the "Locations > Rules" section just below, choose "Show
   this field group if" as "Post Type" -> is equal to -> Games. Save your field group.

Now when editing a game, you should be able to choose two teams to associate with it. You'll need to do a little front-end work to make those teams display and clickable to their single pages, but it shouldn't take more than 10 minutes and the following page can walk you through that process:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

Comment: thanks it works perfectly and very easy but I want to make it by my own (I want to master wordpress), and I needed this kind of plugins it will definitely speed up my work x 10 times.